# Post with react-query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I'm learning react query and i'm trying to post data with it.

I'm able to fetch data with react-query, but I can't do the same posting data. My question is if it's possible to post data with react-query and how to do it.

Thanks :)

Comment: You can send a `POST` request with a normal [query](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/queries), but [mutations](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/mutations) are the idiomatic approach.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a quick example of React Query mutation

```js
const mutation = useMutation({
   mutationFn: (newTodo) => {
     return axios.post('/todos', newTodo)
   },
 })
```

[React Query - Mutations Docs](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/mutations)

Answer (score 1):

in react-query We have 2 most valuable hooks. one for just getting data from the server which is **useQuery()**. the other one is for posting or putting or deleting some data to the server which is **useMutation()**:

- how to work with useMutation():

  ```
  export const usePostData = useMutation({
   mutationFn: your_fetch_request,
   onSuccess:(res)=>{
     console.log(res)
   },
   onError:(err)=>{
     console.log(err)
   }
  })
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Please read [`react-query` docs](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/mutations) clearly, it provides all things about the library.

To fetch (`GET`) data, you can use:

- **`useQuery()`**:   For 1 query at a time
- **`useQueries()`**: For parallel queries at a time
- **`useInfiniteQuery()`**: In case of "infinite scroll"

To create/update/delete (`POST`/`PUT`/`PATCH`/`DELETE`) data, you can use **`useMutation()`**. `useMutation()` returns an object that provides 2 options for you to mutate data:

- **`mutate()`**: To trigger the mutation and optionally hooks on additional callback (onSuccess, onSettled, onError)
- **`mutateAsync()`**: Similar to `mutate()` but returns a promise which can be awaited

Comment: we can use useQuery for POST requests as well if you are just fetching data and not mutating any data on the server. [Here is one such use case](https://dev.to/anjantalatam/can-we-use-usequery-for-post-request-111)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You have just answered my confusing through out the last 7 months (about why I received so many downvotes for my answer).